# jQuery click function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a very simple code with form and one button
with jQuery I want to bind some actions when user clicks on that button, but some reason it's not working

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
 <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script> 
$('#jallerysubmit').bind('click', function() {
 alert('asd');
})
</script> 

<form> 
<input type="checkbox" name="box1">box1<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="box1">box2<br> 
<input type="button" id="jallerysubmit" value="Proved"> 

</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

please suggest what's wrong with this code as it does not work, even it does not produce any error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a `document ready` handler.

```
<script> 
$(function() {
  $('#jallerysubmit').bind('click', function() {
    alert('asd');
  });
});
</script>
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript code will be executed before the DOM is loaded, so the element with ID `jallerysubmit` cannot be found (it does not exists yet).

@sje397 described a very common way (at least when using jQuery) how to solve this. Another way is to put the script at the end of the document:

```
<html> 
   <head> 
       <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="box1">box1<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="box1">box2<br> 
            <input type="button" id="jallerysubmit" value="Proved"> 
        </form>
        <script> 
            $('#jallerysubmit').bind('click', function() {
                 alert('asd');
            });
        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code attaching the handler is being executed before the element exists in the DOM, therefore the selector returns nothing and the handler is not applied.  Put the code inside a document ready handler and it should work.  You could also simplify by using the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click) shortcut.

```
<script> 
   $(function() {
       $('#jallerysubmit').click(function() {
           alert('asd');
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include an alert("hello"); right after  to make sure the jQuery is working right. Then add a return false to the end of your submit handle to make sure your page doesnt reload when the button is clicked, also use document.ready. See code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
 <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("hello");

$('#jallerysubmit').bind('click', function() {
 alert('asd');
 return false;
});

});
</script> 

<form> 
<input type="checkbox" name="box1">box1<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="box1">box2<br> 
<input type="button" id="jallerysubmit" value="Proved"> 

</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is using an external .js file, example script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    yourFunction();
});

function yourFunction() {
    $('#jallerysubmit').click(function() {
        alert('asd');
    });
}
```

and import it in your html file in the tag head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Always use jquery function within***

`(document).ready(function(){//ur jquery codes});`

**or**

```
$().ready(function(){//ur jquery codes});
```

**or**

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){//ur codes});
```

**Once DOM of page is loaded above ready function is initiated. so i recommend jquery lovers to write their magic codes always within this code**